# How do I get taxonomy's current option name?

Tags: bolt-cms

I have a taxonomy.yml file as:

```
categories:
    name: Categories
    slug: categories
    singular_name: Category
    singular_slug: category
    behaves_like: categories
    multiple: true
    options: [ Lighting, Stools, BarCart, Desk, SideBoard, BookShelf, Chairs, AccentChairs, Side Table, Media Unit, Console ]
    listing_template: products.twig
```

Now in `products.twig` template how do I get the current option(lighting in this case) when I am on a url like "/meubles_bolt/categories/lighting"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following in my `listing.twig` template to show the Category title:

```
{% if taxonomytype is defined %}
    <h1 class="listing">
        {{ __('Overview for') }}
        {% if taxonomy.options[slug] is defined %}
            {{ taxonomy.options[slug]|capitalize }}
        {% else %}
            {{ slug|capitalize }}
        {% endif %}
    </h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks again.  Got another question for you, please see if you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980945/mega-drop-down-menu-with-icons