# Mega drop down menu with icons

Tags: bolt-cms

I am having a mega drop down menu with big icons against each menu item. Does the BOLT menu provides a URL option too where I could save the url of that icon and output that Img URL value in loop?

```
main:
    - label: Home
      title: This is the first menu item.
      path: homepage
      class: first
     #imgurl: url <- SOMETHING LIKE THIS #
```

Using class is another option but i don't really want to use CSS pseudo selector here to add background image. Is there any other possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the `imgurl` option to the config. In your template you can access it like `item.imgurl`.

When you look at the default menu implementation, you see that it iterates over the menu items where it calls a function that renders the menu item + any sub menus:
https://github.com/bolt/bolt/blob/release/3.0/app/theme_defaults/_sub_menu.twig#L40-L42

And as you can see in the following link, you just access the options defined on the menu entry.
https://github.com/bolt/bolt/blob/release/3.0/app/theme_defaults/_sub_menu.twig#L20-L22